# How to store and retrieve arrays from sharedpreferences in android?

Tags: android

I have an array, and want to store it in `SharedPreferences` but when I try, it doesn't get saved. Here is the code:

```
editor.putInt("Symptoms Checklist Baseline Matrix", symptoms_checklist_arr_base);
```

Where I have made

```
int symptoms_checklist_arr_base[] = new int[20];
```

In later code, I try to retrieve this value.

```
int symptoms_checklist_arr_base[] = prefs.getInt("Symptoms Checklist Baseline Matrix", what do I add as a default?? );
```

What would I need to do in order to get `SharedPreferences` to store arrays and return them?

Comment: `putInt` puts a single integer, not an array...

Comment: Sorry, I will edit those parentheses out, they were from some experimenting. I am wondering what I should replace putInt with.

Comment: Reading the documentation, you can only put single key-values. Where those values are primitives, not objects. If you want complex data, you'll need to serialize it into a String like JSON or something

Comment: Okay. For now, I will just put the individual values into shared preferences and just work with that unless another answer has a better solution. Thanks

Comment: It is possible to store an array, you just have to save it to a string, then parse it out later. If you are open to using Gson, I can provide an answer

Comment: I think it will be too complex for me. This is my first android project, so I will try to just get a functioning app before trying to use new APIs. Thank you for the offer though.

Comment: I'll toss something together for you to just look at, then. Maybe someone else will find it useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either convert the `Array` into `List` and then store that as a `String` using `ObjectSerializer` or put the `List` itself into a `Parcelable` object.

Refer this question, for implementation using `ObjectSerializer`:
[Save ArrayList to SharedPreferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences)

Refer this question, for implementation using `Parcelable`:
[Pass ArrayList<? implements Parcelable> to Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133121/pass-arraylist-implements-parcelable-to-activity)

Comment: Links are great, but you could [answer the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) here as well