# Populating List<Service> into android ListView giving different value

Tags: android, listview

I have a `List<Service>` received from `getParcelableArrayListExtra()` Now I need to populate the received objects into a android ListView

I have try to populate the ListView in the following way. The ListView is populated to show the Object reference ids. Instead of showing contants.

How do i show the contents in this list.

The implementation is as follow :

```
List<Service> serviceCart = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("serviceCart");

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_choosed_services);

ArrayAdapter<Service> serviceArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Service>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,serviceCart);

listView.setAdapter(serviceArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: where is serviceCart?

Comment: List<Service> serviceCart = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("serviceCart");

Comment: serviceCart is a List<Service> of Service object

Comment: have you put in Service class: public class Service implements Parcelable  ?

Comment: Yes. This is my service class https://gist.github.com/nifrasismail/22d1952a7304e1fdd2bd3a8c784d6f79

Comment: Using Log.d("TAG SERVICE",serviceCart.toString()); I could able to see the objects received as List<Service> too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133121/pass-arraylist-implements-parcelable-to-activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `ArrayAdapter` and go to read from line no 405 to 410

```
final T item = getItem(position);
if (item instanceof CharSequence) {
    text.setText((CharSequence) item);
} else {
    text.setText(item.toString());
}
```

**What you are doing:**

If your item is `String` `Adpater.getView(params)` will use it, otherwise it will use `item.toString()`. In your `Service.java` you don't have a `toString()` so application uses default default `toString()`

**What you should do:**

- Its best to create custom `ArrayAdapter` and populate your view
- Override `toString()` in your `Service.java` and use only those values you want to populate in your adapter like `service_name` and/or `service_code` and default implementation will do the rest.

**Note:**
Please read [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), its not recommended to name your objects like `service_name` it should be `serviceName`.