# ArrayList and Parcelable

Tags: android, arraylist, parcelable

I need to "transfer" an ArrayList of custom class from one entity to another. I know that I need to implement Parcelable interface.

This is my custom class.

```
public class cSportsList implements Parcelable {
    boolean checked;
    String name;

    cSportsList(boolean check, String name_) {
        checked = check;
        name = name_;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        //Non posso passare un booleano e non posso fare il cast boolean -> int
        if (checked) {
            dest.writeInt(1);
        }
        else dest.writeInt(0);
        dest.writeString(name);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<cSportsList> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<cSportsList>() {
        public cSportsList createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new cSportsList(in);
        }

        public cSportsList[] newArray(int size) {
            return new cSportsList[size];
        }
    };

    private cSportsList(Parcel in) {
        if (in.readInt() == 1) {
            checked = true;
        }
        else {
            checked = false;
        }
        name = in.readString();


    }
}
```

And this is the code in entity "from"

```
//This is sportsMap: ArrayList<cSportsList> sportsMap = new ArrayList<cSportsList>();
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),WhatSportActivity.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("sportsMap", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>)  sportsMap);  //I have tried with ArrayList<cSportsList> too.
this.startActivity(intent);
```

And this is the code in entity "to"

```
final Intent srcIntent = getIntent();
ArrayList<cSportsList> sportsMap = srcIntent.getParcelableExtra("sportsMap");
```

The problem is: in entity "To" sportsMap is null. 
If I set "breakpoint" in "writeToParcel" and "cSportsList(Parcelable in)" functions I see that the code is executed for both functions.

Where is my error ?

Thanks. M.

Comment: replace **getParcelableExtra** with **getParcelableArrayListExtra**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code

sportsMap = srcIntent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("sportsMap");

Answer (score 1):

While reading you need to use

```
srcIntent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("sportsMap");
```

---

To put into Intent use below code

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("sportsMap", sportsMap);
```

and to read it from intent, use

```
ArrayList<cSportsList> sportsMap = srcIntent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("sportsMap");
```

---

Read similar solution at [Pass ArrayList<? implements Parcelable> to Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133121/pass-arraylist-implements-parcelable-to-activity)

Answer (score 0):

You should use :

```
ArrayList<cSportsList> sportsMap = srcIntent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("sportsMap");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Serialization for the same.

`public class cSportsList implements Serializable`

for put:

`intent.putExtra("LIST",list);`

for get:

`(ArrayList<>)intent.getSerializableExtra("LIST");`

Comment: I have read that Parcelable is better than Serialize. But however: thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing Arraylist instead of casting it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),WhatSportActivity.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("sportsMap", sportsMap);
        startActivity(intent);
```

In WhatSportActivity,

```
final Intent srcIntent = getIntent();
ArrayList<cSportsList> sportsMap = srcIntent.getParcelableExtra("sportsMap");
```

In case you still have problems,please try implementing Parceable by using "Parceable"plugin as It reduces the error in using Parceable lists.