# intent.putExtra a list of Parcelable objects and enums

Tags: android, parcelable

This question is different from all the other questions because here the list of parcelable objects is created outside on the fly just sending it before via Intent.

Problem: Product is parcelable but the custom `List<Product>` is not. How to make the `List` `Parcelable`??

**Product**

```
public class Product implements Parcelable {

    public String id;
    public String name;

    public Product(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    protected Product(Parcel in) {
        id = in.readString();
        name = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Product> CREATOR = new Creator<Product>() {
        @Override
        public Product createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Product(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Product[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Product[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(id);
        parcel.writeString(name);
    }
}
```

**Activity class**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowProducts.class);
List<Product> products = getSpecificProducts();

intent.putExtra("PRODUCTS", products); // error

startActivity(intent);
```

---

**Edit**

The question is two fold, it's not a duplicate, the other part is `List<Enum>`

```
public enum Department implements Parcelable {

    SALES("Sales", 0),
    HR("HR", 1),

    public String name;
    public int ordinal;

    Department(String name, int ordinal) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ordinal = ordinal;
    }

    public static final Creator<Department> CREATOR = new Creator<Department>() {
        @Override
        public Department createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return Department.values()[in.readInt()];
        }

        @Override
        public Department[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Department[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeInt(ordinal);
    }

}
```

Based on the suggested answers, I've tried.

```
List<Department> departments = getSpecificDepartments();

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Departments", departments);
```

> error: incompatible types: `List<Department>` cannot be converted to
>   `ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>`

Comment: With Pojo, You can try to encode it into JSON and parse it later via Gson from Google.

Comment: @AdmiralKunkka Are you sure about that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass ArrayList<? implements Parcelable> to Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133121/pass-arraylist-implements-parcelable-to-activity)

Comment: @GensaGames your answer is quite correct. I just give another option to solve his problem. And yes, any plain java object or list contain those objects can be serializable to JSON by Gson.

Comment: @AdmiralKunkka Are you sure? Another options to double serialize to JSON, to Parcelable and then double deserialize back?

Comment: @GensaGames I mean encode to JSON string, send Extra with `.putString("data", str)`. And then later in next activity, parsing it back to Object (or List) to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to make List parcelable. To put it, just use existing method.

```
final Intent i = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
final ArrayList<Product> list = new ArrayList< Product >();
i.putParcelableArrayListExtra(PRODUCT_KEY, list);
startActivity(i);
```

To retrieve almost in the same way.

```
final ArrayList<Product> list = this.getIntent()
            .getParcelableArrayListExtra(PRODUCT_KEY);
```

**UPDATE**

To answer you newer question. You cannot pass generic `List` inside. Because by `List` you could have different collection. To know system, which type to use you need to have explicit type.

```
// This will work. 
final ArrayList<Department> departments = getSpecificDepartments();
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(DEPARTMENTS_KEY, departments);
```

Comment: there's an error for this line -> `intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(DEPARTMENTS_KEY, departments);`

Comment: it has a problem with list of enums

Answer (score 2):

Use `putParcelableArrayListExtra` method like this:

```
ArrayList<Product> products = getSpecificProducts();
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("PRODUCTS", products);
```

Comment: We Practically posted at the same time. I saw the question and answered it. I just didn't refresh the page before posting the answer. What's with the down vote dude? This is a community to help others. Judgement for correct answer is with the person who asked it, which he/her probably will accept your answer since it is posted earlier. You are misleading others with down votes.

Comment: sorry i stepped out a bit and came back to desk, I actually have this as a two issue, please see my edit, your answer is right, if you can add the other extra bit, I'd really appreciate.

Comment: You should use an ArrayList not a List.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
var intent = Intent(this, ActivityB::class.java)
val list = arrayListOf<Person>()
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("LIST", list)
```